# format all values into thousands using sap.ui.core.format.NumberFormat

Tags: formatting, sapui5, number-formatting, sap-fiori

Currently I am formatting a float value using NumberFormat class with the formatOptions being:

```
formatOptions: {
  style : 'short', 
  shortDecimals: 1
}
```

https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.format.NumberFormat.html

So a value 5,000,000 is displayed as 5.0 M using the current formatter I have.

I was wondering if there is a trivial way using the formatter to force all values into any other denominations(maybe thousands for instance).

i.e 5 M should be formatted as 5000 K.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no trivial way. ['short' is a special CLDR number pattern](http://cldr.unicode.org/translation/number-patterns#TOC-Short-Numbers). The denomination is configured in the localization: The is an entry for each magnitude in each language. So you would have to change the localization data for your language (and probably for the other languages too) or create a new language and use that for your `NumberFormat`.

If you want to have a fixed denomination i would recommend to use a custom formatter function or a custom data type. [Here's an example](https://jsbin.com/viviyixupe/1/edit?html,js,output) of a formatter function:

```js
formatThousands:function(value){
   var numberFormat = NumberFormat.getFloatInstance({maxFractionDigits:1});
   var text = numberFormat.format(value/1000)+" K";
   return text;
}
```

Comment: Can you just `return numberFormat.format(value/1000)+" K";` to remove the extraneous variable `text`?

Comment: of course you can shorten it in that way. I would also recommend to promote the numberFormat to a member of your controller, create it once and reuse it in the formatter for performance reasons.